# Flutter - ListView.builder - detect if ListTile is visible or not - how to show only a single Admob banner ad at at time on the screen

Tags: admob, flutter-listview

Only a single Admob ad can be shown on a screen. How would I show an Admob ad in a ListTile in a ListView.builder, and detect once the user scrolls down and the ad is no longer visible, and add another at the end of the screen?
PS I got the first part just fine, but how do I detect if a ListTile is no longer visible in the screen?

Comment: You can have multiple Ads in a listview as long as they are not shown at the same time. Better to add them at a pre-defined interval, for example: say every 10 items after scroll.